# Extracting Matrix from txt file

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following model summary in txt file (T1.txt):

```
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         423               88.6792 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        54               11.3208 %
Kappa statistic                          0.6766
Mean absolute error                      0.0854
Root mean squared error                  0.2656
Relative absolute error                 38.4098 %
Root relative squared error             79.9279 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)          91.6143 %
Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      36.1985 %
Total Number of Instances              477     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 357  20   7 |   a = 1
  12  37  11 |   b = 2
   3   1  29 |   c = 3
```

I would like to extract the last matrix into dataframe (df1):

```
> df1
       a   b   c   
     357  20   7 
      12  37  11 
       3   1  29
```

We have to take into consideration that the model behind the txt file doesn't exist any more (I have only the txt file). In addition, the matrix size can be varied from one file to another and its number of rows doesn't have to be equal to the number of columns.

Comment: Based on the previous question, I guess you solved it..  Do you have the contents in the text file exactly as you showed it?

Comment: I'd probably rather use Perl for such a problem.

Comment: @akrun, No the difference between the 2 questions is that in the previous one  I had the model and could extract it analytically and here I have only txt without the model (As mentioned in the question body)

Comment: Unless you have literally thousands of these files, it might be easier to use the regex command functionality in something like notepad++

Comment: Do you have this pattern repeating in the file? i.e. Summary followed by Confusion Matrix, again Summary....

Comment: @Serban Tanasa, I do have many of these files. That's why I asked my question,

Comment: @akrun, As I analyzed the content of files: The matrix appears at the end of the file, starts with the header: Confusion Matrix and each row content  (except for the header) ends with '|'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can read the file using `readLines`, `grep` to find the line that has 'Confusion Matrix', subset the lines, use `gsub` to remove the substring, and read with `read.table`

```
lines <- readLines('Avi.txt', warn=FALSE)
i1 <- grep('Confusion Matrix', lines)
read.table(text=gsub('(<-|\\|).*', '', 
        lines[(i1+2):length(lines)]), header=TRUE)
#    a  b  c
#1 357 20  7
#2  12 37 11
#3  3  1 29
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, too lazy to write it up :)

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Thanks for the comment.  This will not work if there are multiple instances (which the OP doesn't have)

Comment: @Avi If you have multiple instances `i1 <- grep('Confusion Matrix', lines)
i2 <- c(grep('Summary', lines)[-1]-1, length(lines))
 lapply(Map(seq, i1, i2), function(x) {x1 <- lines[x[-1]]; read.table(text=gsub('(<-|\\|).*', '', x1[nzchar(x1)]), header=TRUE)` should work